# Flutter Firebase dynamic links always redirect to app store on iOS yet working on android

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I noticed that there're already several related questions here, I checked my firebase console that I have the correct bundle ID, team ID and app ID entered but still the dynamic link only redirects to app store. I have also checked that the configuration in the Associated Domains in XCode is correct. I have tested the dynamic links on both iOS 13 and 14 and they both doesn't work.

One interesting thing is that when I open the app manually after the dynamic link redirects me to the app store, the app goes to the specific page according to my dynamic link. So it is possible that the app did read the dynamic link afterwards but the link could not be opened in the app when I clicked it (or entered it directly in safari/chrome).

I'd be really really thankful if anyone have any idea to my situation.

---

Updates: I deleted the ios files of my flutter project and rebuilt them with `flutter create .` and the problem is solved, so if anyone is also stuck this might be as well the way out.

Comment: I have exactly same issue.

Comment: Also check here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2585

Answer (score 0):

Try reinitializing Firebase Dynamic Links for the Flutter app again. It's possible that it wasn't set up properly. To rebuild platform-specific builds, you can delete the build folder i.e. `/ios`, then run

`flutter create --platforms=ios`

Follow the [setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive) on the docs and make sure that the [app preview page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews#app_preview_pages) isn't disabled because this helps with FDL app redirects on iOS.